# AngularJS http get json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, rest

First time trying to get json data and bind it to my form using AngularJS. I am able to bind the json this way but it requires I manually match "data" to each of my items in my html.

http call from my controller:

```
  $http.get('static.json').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // here I have to manually copy all my json to bind with "data"
      $scope.SiteID = data.SiteID;
      $scope.SiteCode = data.SiteCode;
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // log error
  });
```

My json:

```
{
  "SiteID":"mySiteIDGoesHere",
  "SiteCode":"mySiteCodeGoesHere"
}
```

Is there a way to automatically bind my json without having to go through each item manually? eg:

```
  $http.get('static.json').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      "just pull in whatever my json is and bind it"
      $scope.WhateverIsInJSONID = data.WhateverIsInJSONID;
      $scope.WhateverIsInJSONCode = data.WhateverIsInJSONCode;
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // log error
  });
```

Comment: Just set `$scope.something = data` and then your views will be like: `{{something.WhateverIsInJSONID}}`, or whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your success function, bind your data to $scope.data like so:

```
$scope.data = data
```

Then  - within your html, all your ng-models, ng-values, etc would be bound as such:

```
<p>{{data.someKey}}</p><img ng-src="data.imgSrc" />....
```

In addition, its unsafe to strap many keys in an arbitrary fashion to scope. And I don't mean the occasional .data or .whatever being added to scope. But when you blindly iterate an object and strap each key on to $scope, you run the risk of overwriting some other key that may already be set or the key your setting be overwritten later in the controller. Perhaps you have a function attached to scope that gets overwritten by blind assigning, or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

You could just set `$scope.data = data;`...

Then in your view you could access `data.SiteID`, or `data.SiteCode`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you can simply set an item on the `$scope` to `data` and then reference it using dot notation, like:

```
$scope.data = data;
```

And then:

```
<span>{{data.WhateverIsInJSONID}}</span>
```

If you want each property on the `$scope` individually, you would have to loop through them and add them, something like:

```
for (var property in data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
    $scope[property] = data[property];
  }
}
```

Which would give you `$scope.WhateverIsInJSONID` and `$scope.WhateverIsInJSONCode`

Comment: Downside of your for loop example is the potential for overwriting a previous key attached to scope. For instance a $scope.someKey = function... and you then have .someKey in your returned data object for which you then overwrite your function. Unsafe.

Comment: @Brant, agreed, I wouldn't do it this way, but to satisfy the question I added it.

Comment: Figured you added for that reason.

Answer (score -2):

No. In angular you have to put data in scope($scope) one by one inside controller then you can access it in HTML either {{blah}} or use of ng-models directive ,ng-values etc.